# Java: Interaction/connection of Android UI (Android Studio) and java backend (model) (in comparison to JavaFX)

Tags: java, android, javafx

I'm quite new to programming and started with Java, went to JavaFX as GUI development and just tackled Android App Development with Android Studio.

Coming from JavaFX and its concept of having the UI connected to a backend controller I am a bit confused about the (apprently) much more complex interaction of Android UI with the Java backend (controller, model).

My scenario: I programmed a game application with JavaFX which works quite fine. I applied the MVC concept whereas I used FXML to construct the UI, had a Controller.java class which "connected" all UI elements via @FXML to my controller class and then I could - cross-method within the controller - access my UI elements (e.g. for reading values from sliders, or changing them), like:

```
@FXML
private text label;

public void readLabel(){

String labelText = label.getText();
}
```

Now: In Android (using Android Studio) I tried to apply the same concept/idea but failed because obviously the various views, buttons, texts respectively have their own classes which need to be casted to one another so that their content can be used.

So I followed the Android concept and tried to initially declare all UI elements within the MainActivity class as follows:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText inputText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.text1);
    EditText outputText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textOutput);
    Button enterButton = (Button) findViewByID(R.id.button1);

...
```

This is because I want to reuse (simply access/change) them in different methods within the MainActivity.
The above approach failed due to a NullPointerException. I tried to initialize the respective objects with, e.g.:

```
Button button1 = new Button();
```

but this didnt work either.

However if I use above approach WITHIN a method of the MainActivity, it works fine:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

public void enterMessage(View view){

        EditText inputText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.text1);
        String textOutput = inputText.getText().toString();

        EditText outputText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textOutput);
        outputText.setText(textOutput);

    }
```

and I can read and change my UI objects.

I then had the idea of making a static "controller method" within the MainActivity so that I can access my UI elements from any other method within my MainActivity. But this dindnt work out because

```
findViewById()
```

doesnt go along with static methods.

So the only way I see right now after trying these different approaches, is to create new objects and cast them to the required variable, like:

```
EditText inputText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.text1);
String textOutput = inputText.getText().toString();
```

in EVERY method which I want to create within the MainActivity.

Now my question: Is the concept with the Android UI classes indeed that more complex in comparison to JavaFX or do I just get it wrong somewhere with the basics? Any hint for a best practice is much appreciated. :)

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

What is way more complex is [the lifecycle](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle) of the views inside the Android Application. In Java's Swing for instance there's no such thing as lifecycle of a view/controller and I don't know about JavaFX. The underlying platforms are not the same although the programming languages are.

Android comes from a context where devices barely had any available memory and very little computational power. For that, Android tries to save as much resources as it can.

You must listen for the Activities lifecycle events since they may affect whether your View objects are still there or not. For instance: You may have your `MainActivity` instance running but by simply turning the phone in landscape mode makes your current `MainActivity` die and get a new instance with the updated View.

[image: Android activity lifecycle]

So you'll find yourself writing lots of `findViewById` during your Android App Development. But there are solutions to make Android development a little bit easier.

By seeing your experience with `@FXML` I would suggest you take a look to [ButterKnife](https://jakewharton.github.io/butterknife/) which is an annotation processor that takes care of `findingViewById` for you and it may help you a lot. Looks like the way of consuming the views is similar

Also take a look to [Android's Architecture components](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/docs/guide) since they leverage a lot of boilerplate code and allow you to focus on what you want to write. Specially [DataBinding](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/)

I would also strongly suggest you take a look into Kotlin, since it runs on the JVM and you can use it both for Android and Java development. Turns out it is a really fun language to use and quite efficient speaking in terms of the amount of code you have to write to get something done.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Some random IT boy for guidance.

Actually my problem/confusion is solved now. What I can recommend, in order to have a much more simplified GUI-backend interaction is to use the new View binding feature.

View binding (https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding) is available in Android Studio 3.6 Canary 11+. Right now this means to install the pre-final version of Android Studio but with that it works just fine.

View binding is a standardized feature which actually provides similar functionality as Butter Knife. As per the Butter Knife website "view binding" appears to be the feature-wise successor.

The instructions of how to use view binding are included in the link above. Following the steps there lets you interact with Android GUI similarly to the approach in JavaFX.